# How to answer yes in Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash

Have a quick question,

imagine that I have this code:

```
mkdir -p $INSTALLDIR
sudo apt-get install -y git clojure leiningen
git clone git://github.com/maltoe/storm-install.git
./storm-install/storm_install.sh all `hostname` $INSTALLDIR
```

And this script will ask, do you want to install additional packages, and I want to say `yes`,
How to do this automatically?

Or may be there is a way to kinda answer yes to any question by default?

Comment: [yes](http://linux.die.net/man/1/yes), there is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

assume storm asks the question  - use a here document - example:

```
mkdir -p $INSTALLDIR
sudo apt-get install -y git clojure leiningen
git clone git://github.com/maltoe/storm-install.git
./storm-install/storm_install.sh all `hostname` $INSTALLDIR  <<-EOF
yes
EOF
```

The EOF can be any nonsense characters the shell will not interpret.

Answer (score 15):

If you are running a script, try this:

```
yes "yes" | bash script.sh
```

Answer (score 14):

I not sure but i advice try:

```
echo yes | ./storm-install/storm_install.sh all `hostname` $INSTALLDIR
```

Answer (score 10):

With the command appropriately named [`yes`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/yes)

Answer (score 4):

```
( echo yes ; echo no; echo yes ) | script.sh
```

Answer (score 3):

`apt` has also `--force-yes` option which may be helpful:

```
   --force-yes
       Force yes; This is a dangerous option that will cause apt to
       continue without prompting if it is doing something potentially
       harmful. It should not be used except in very special situations.
       Using force-yes can potentially destroy your system! Configuration
       Item: APT::Get::force-yes.
```