# Using Bash Alias to Update and Open Anaconda Navigator?

Tags: bash, anaconda, alias

I currently run Linux Mint 20 and Anaconda Navigator 2.04 on an HP laptop, all fairly standard(at least to me). I have Bash aliases that I use to update Anaconda and to startup Anaconda Navigator.

I find Anaconda(alias condaup) needs updating almost daily and I am prompted with the usual `[y]/n`.
I also had an alias for Anaconda Navigator to open it. They both work well.

However, When I put the two aliases together(alias navi) I would like the update to default to yes instead of waiting for human intervention. Is there a way to do this?

```
alias condaup='conda update --prefix /home/aaa/anaconda3 anaconda'
alias navi='conda update --prefix /home/aaa/anaconda3 anaconda && anaconda-navigator'
```

Comment: Please make an attempt to read documentation: `conda update --help`. Also, consider using [Mamba](https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba#readme) for the updating part.

Comment: I was thinking (more) along the line of [how-to-answer-yes-in-bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616120/how-to-answer-yes-in-bash-script) but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation can be consulted with

```bash
conda update --help
```

which shows the relevant flag:

```bash
  -y, --yes    Do not ask for confirmation.
```

That is, you want

```bash
alias condaup='conda update -y --prefix /home/aaa/anaconda3 anaconda'
alias navi='conda update -y --prefix /home/aaa/anaconda3 anaconda && anaconda-navigator'
```